# vb.net - error handling on main method or every method

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, try-catch, vb6-migration

I have a program that is interacting with emails. I am upgrading it from `vb6` to `vb.net`. There was extensive error handling in the program before ,using `On Error` commands, to ensure that it never broke, just ignored and logged the errors. In most functions there is this `On Error` code, where it handles an error in the function by returning a default value and exiting the function. For Example:

```
Public Function Init() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err_Init
    Init = True
Exit_Init: 
    Exit Function 
Err_Init:
    Init = False
    Resume Exit_Init
End Function
```

I want to change all error handling to `Try - Catch` blocks. My initial thought when I was upgrading the `vb6` code was to replace all error handling with a simple `Try - Catch` around the `Sub Main` entry point, as below:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Try
        Init()
    catch
        'do stuff
    end try
End Sub
```

---

```
public function Init() As boolean
    init = true
end function
```

as any errors in the program would be caught in this way and I could handle them all in one `Try - Catch`.

However I then realised that, that would not make the function above return a value of `False` when an error occurred. If I still want this functionality do I have to wrap everything in `Try` blocks?

Comment: If you only have a `Try...Catch` block in the main function, then when an error occurs in the `Init()` function for example, execution of `Init()` will stop and the program flow would fall into the catch block of the `Main()` function, therefore it wouldn't actually hit any return statements persay, right?

Comment: exactly my problem, because some functions do need to have return statements even if an error does occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your concern is that you do not want the application to crash or break, Yes you can use Try cache block for that concern.
However, If you are talking about error handling in the whole application, then I would suggest that you think of a way to refactor the whole code.
Remove all the "On Error" statements and apply some new logic to handle the errors.
That logic could vary (Only logging, Retrying strategy Design pattern, etc) Think of all the expected errors and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something special for errors in a particular function, then the function should have its own Try/Catch block to implement that behavior. For example:

```
Public Function Init() As Boolean
    Try
        'Presumably some other code goes here
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the on Error steps and do the error handling globally

In the main_load put the three block below

```
       ' Get your application's application domain for error handling.
    Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain

    ' Define a handler for unhandled exceptions.
    AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MYExnHandler

    ' Define a handler for unhandled exceptions for threads behind forms.
    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf MYThreadHandler
```

and then add the two sub routines shown below

```
Private Sub MYExnHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
   ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)

    Dim EX As Exception
    EX = e.ExceptionObject
    If EX.StackTrace.Contains("SOMETHING") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LogToWrite, "Error SOMETHING caught:" & EX.StackTrace & vbCrLf, True, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        MsgBox("error caught. Contact **XXX** for assistance!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error: " & vbCrLf & EX.StackTrace,, "Fatal Error")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MYThreadHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
 ByVal e As Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
    If e.Exception.StackTrace.Contains("SOMETHING") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LogToWrite, "Error SOETHING caught:" & e.Exception.StackTrace & vbCrLf, True, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        MsgBox("Error caught. Contact **xxx** for assistance!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error: " & vbCrLf & e.Exception.StackTrace,, "Fatal Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

You can just check the content of the errors and respond accordingly to every single error with a Case Array..